# When custom UITableViewCell gets highlighted, it all turns blue

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a custom uitableviewcell using a xib file. the cell contains a view which contains a couple of labels and an image. it all works great, even resizing, but when I select the cell instead of just the background view ( the view containing the labels and etc ) turning blue, the entire cell gets filled with blue.
How can I solve this?
Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour for selecting a cell.
Within your xib you can change the selected-color of your cell (it's a property within object inspector). If you want the blue color to disappear you could set its alpha channel and so it will not be visible any more.
Or you pick another color, it's up to you :)

Comment: I do want the blue to be visible - just under the labels and etc, not above.

Comment: Set the background-color of your labels and other elements to white or something else. If a cell is selected their background-color is changed. Default background-color of new elements shall be a transparent color. So setting it to white or something else should prevent the blue shining through this element. Unfortunately I'm not able to test it, I don't have my Mac around here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are assigning your custom view to the **contentView** property of the table view cell.